# Microsoft Graph: how to get all groups reusing the token generated through ADAL

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph and I'm a little bit lost here. I'm using ADAL to authenticate my app (app id + secret) through the AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync method. The code looks like this:

```
AuthenticationContext AuthContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
ClientCredential ClientCredential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, AppKey);
var result = await AuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                                        "https://graph.windows.net", 
                                        ClientCredential);
```

Now, if I reuse the token with the Azure Graph, I can recover all the groups by using this code:

```
var url = $"https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups?api-version=1.6";
 var client = new HttpClient();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", resultAccessToken);
  var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
  if (response.Content != null) {
       Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
  }
```

According to the docs, I should use the newer Microsoft Graph API, but I'm having some issues when I try to use the following code:

```
var authenticationProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
      req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", 
                                           resultAccessToken.AccessToken);
      return Task.CompletedTask;
});
var graph = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
var groups = await graph.Groups
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();
```

Whenever I run this, I end up getting the following exception:

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Message: Access token validation failure.

It's obvious that I'm missing something here, but what? (btw, I've managed to get everything working with the MSAL libraries, but in this case, I really need to have my component integrated with others that use ADAL),

Thanks.

Luis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AAD Graph and the Microsoft Graph have different physical endpoints.

To call the AAD Graph, you need a token with the Audience Claim `https://graph.windows.net`

To call the Microsoft Graph, you need a token with the Audience Claim `https://graph.microsoft.com`

This means you need to do 2 things:

1. Make sure your application is configured to the Microsoft Graph. (This means you need to update your application's configuration to call other resources)
2. Update your code to request a token for the right resource.

I hope this helps!